# Minimum Viewport Width in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

How do I set the minimum viewport width in Chrome?

I put this in the head of the document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And this for CSS:

```
@viewport {
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `@viewport` rule has [very poor browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-deviceadaptation) at this time.

Comment: What could I use for a work around?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different, but I think it might have the same effect you are trying to achieve. Try viewing the code below in `Full Page` and resizing your browser. The body is the same width as the browser window but has a `min-width` of `700px`.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<h1>Some Text</h1>
```

Comment: No luck with the above. That only resizes the inner content, not the browser window.

Comment: That is the point. All your html should be inside the body tag so could you just style that? Can you post a little more detail about what specifically you are trying to achieve.